# Web Scraper (using puppeteer) only adding the first instance of the html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping

My scraper is only taking in the first class/classname instance but not the rest on the page

I've tried using a normal for loop instead of for-each, I thought that it's because the div has a unique classname that increases by a set value. I tried increasing that within the loop, but to no avail.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const siteUrl = "https://toronto.iabc.com/about/pic/pic-member-list/";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
  await page.goto(siteUrl);

  //getting details of member list

  const siteData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pageData = [];
    //get page elements
    const pageElms = document.querySelectorAll(
      "body > div.site-container > div.site-inner > div > main > article"
    );
    let num = 3;

    //parse data from elements
    const scraper = pageElms.forEach(element => {
      let nextPerson = (num += 2);
      const pageJson = {};
      try {
        if (nextPerson > 50) {
          return pageData;
        }
        pageJson.name = element.querySelector(
          `body > div.site-container > div.site-inner > div > main > article > div > div:nth-child(${nextPerson}) > div:nth-child(1) > div`
        ).innerText;

        scraper();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      pageData.push(pageJson);
      console.log(pageData);
    });
    return pageData;
  });
  console.dir(siteData);
})();
```

at the end of it all, I should be able to scrape every single person from this list with a few tweaks to specify the selector I'd like to scrape.

Comment: There is only one article tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one article tag in the page you have shared. So the loop doesn't really make sense here. Also I suggest you include the mark up in the question.

If you to change the initial selector to the below, where I am targeting the row in which the info is

```
 const pageElms = document.querySelectorAll(
      "body > div.site-container > div.site-inner > div > main > article > div > div.su-row"
    );
```

and use

```
 pageJson.name = element.innerText;
```

You don't need to generate the nextPerson and you will be scraping all the data

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I definitely think I spent too much time thinking about something simple like this.